# Check with VBA if given range is valid or not

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a range variable stored as string. I just ant to check the given range is valid or not. For example: `A11:Z4, D8:H7, B112:H80, M5:P45` not valid, `A5:A5` not valid (one scenario), `A11:Z11, D8:H8, A5:M5` is valid. I just want to get in same row, different columns.

How can we do this?

Comment: Why is `M5:P45` not valid?

Comment: Is the range `"A5,D5,G5:H5"` meant to be returned as valid or invalid?  It is a single row, and four different columns, so in theory meets your requirements.

Comment: @Mahesh I want same row only, so when it M5:P45 not valid.

Comment: @YowE3K A5:H5,D5:H5,G5:H5 are valid

Comment: @KaviSuja I am referring to the single range which is `"A5,D5,G5:H5"`.  Is that to be treated as valid or invalid?  Do you require a valid range to be contiguous cells?

Comment: Contiguous cells not allowed, single range which is "A5,D5,G5:H5" is invalid

Comment: @KaviSuja, you don't give clear goal definitions, but mostly show only a variety of wanted results thus leaving room for interpretation.
So it's hard to find presumptive solutions by the need of subsequent follow ups occupying at least three users.  Maybe you could a) refine your original question or b) at least accept one of the given answers, if helpful.

Comment: @KaviSuja, is it correct, that you want to have marked a) one cell values and apparently descending ranges as "invalid" and b) only one liners with more than one column as "valid"? If so I'd suggest that you edit this in your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I just used the below method to solve this issue.

```
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim retval As String
                Dim retval1 As String
                Dim colFrom As String
                Dim colTo As String

        'Example : FromRange = A5, ToRange =D5
                If FromRange = ToRange  Then  'For Same Column
                    MsgBox "The Input Range specified is invalid"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                colFrom = FromRange 
                colTo = ToRange  
        'Get the numbers only from given range and compare it
                For i = 1 To Len(colFrom)
                    If Mid(colFrom, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(colFrom, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                        retval = retval + Mid(colFrom, i, 1)
                    End If
                Next

                For i = 1 To Len(colTo)
                    If Mid(colTo, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(colTo, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                        retval1 = retval1 + Mid(colTo, i, 1)
                    End If
                Next

                If retval <> "" And retval1 <> "" And retval = retval1 Then
                    myCellRange= FromRange  & ":" & ToRange  
                Else
                    MsgBox "Input Range is invalid"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code you can use:

```
Sub Validate()
Dim rng As String
'here you can define your range
rng = "C11:D12"

If Range(rng).Rows.Count = 1 And Range(rng).Columns.Count > 1 And Range(rng).Areas.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Range is valid"
Else
    MsgBox "Range is invalid"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Michal why here Range(rng).Rows.Count = 1 here we check? It is not working if D5:M5. Actually I need to copy the range, after D5 there will be rows which i copied. So in this case Range(rng).Rows.Count always > 1 most of the time

Comment: @KaviSuja `Range("D5:M5").Rows.Count` will be equal to 1.  (There is only one row, row 5, in that range.)  If your range includes extra rows, e.g. `"D5:M10"`, then by your own definition that range is invalid.

Comment: @YowE3K Corrected :)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you print out a Range object's address inside VBA, it'll print the address in proper order. So, if you pass it `A6:A5`, it'll know that you're actually referring to `A5:A6`.</strike>

You can use that to create a UDF:

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question. So, I've modified my answer to make rectify the mistakes.

**Note**: This is basically Michal Turczyn's answer, rewritten in the form of a UDF:

```
Function IS_RANGE_VALID(s As String) As Boolean
    IS_RANGE_VALID = (Range(s).Rows.Count = 1 And Range(s).Columns.Count > 1)
End Function
```

The result:

```
╔═══╦══════════╦═══════╗
║   ║    A     ║   B   ║
╠═══╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 1 ║ A11:Z4   ║ FALSE ║
║ 2 ║ D8:H7    ║ FALSE ║
║ 3 ║ B112:H80 ║ FALSE ║
║ 4 ║ M5:P45   ║ FALSE ║
║ 5 ║ A5:A5    ║ FALSE ║
║ 6 ║ A11:Z11  ║ TRUE  ║
║ 7 ║ D8:H8    ║ TRUE  ║
║ 8 ║ A5:M5    ║ TRUE  ║
╚═══╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

<strike>**Note**: Like I asked you in the comment, why is `M5:P45` invalid? If it was a typo, then this should work for you. Otherwise you'll have to be clearer about the criterion you're using to determine validity of a range.</strike>

Comment: For one scenario the row number should be equal like M5:P5 or M45:P45

Comment: @KaviSuja, I don't get you. If you mean to say that `M5:P5` should be flagged as valid, then this function should satisfy your needs. Or do you want it be flagged as invalid? Or do you need two cases, one of which says it's valid and the other says it's not?

Comment: The OP wants `M5:P45` flagged as invalid because it includes 41 rows - their criteria is that the range is "in same row, different columns".

Comment: Yes, M5:P45 is invalid

Comment: IMO KaviSuja wants to have marked a) one cell values and apparently descending ranges as "invalid" and b) only one liners with more than one column as "valid", so that @Michal-Turcziyn 's answer should be correct. I can't see a hint to non contiguous ranges in OP.

Comment: @T.M., Yeah I understand that now. So Michal Turczyn's answer is the correct

Comment: @Mahesh, +1 as I liked your original approach finding apparently descending ranges by returning a boolean value `IS_RANGE_VALID = (Range(s).Address(0, 0) = s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsVal(iAdd As String) As Boolean
      
    'if iAdd is specified above Cell Level, it must exist in an Open Workbook
    '   eg "[Book1.xls]Sheet1!A11:Z4"

    Dim zRa As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set pZ.Ra = Evaluate(iAdd)
    IsVal = Err.Number = 0
    Err.Clear

    End Function
```